# How do I import a database into PGmyadmin IV

Tags: postgresql

I cannot imort database in postgresql. I'm typing

```
psql –U postgres isonis_klijent < / isonis_klijent_backup
```

in cmd administrator mode and it says access denied. What is the problem? I have added a line in the pg_hba.conf file under # IPv4 local connections line host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

If this doesn't make sense, my question is simple: How do I dump a database into an empty one I have made ? I am give a database by the name iconic.sql

Comment: "Access denied" is pretty obvious: apparently you aren't allowed to access the file `isonis_klijent_backup` or that file doesn't exist. Also: are you **really** typing `< / isonis_klijent_backup` What is the `/` supposed to do there? Please **[edit]** your question and add the ***exact*** error message you get.

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified." when I removed the "/" and when I type with "/" i get the message: Access is denied. Where do the files need to be located? And also in which directory do I need to be in, in the commend prompt.

Comment: What's unclear about "*The system cannot find the file specified*"?

Comment: In the command prompt I am in the folder where this database, which needs to be imported is in.